# How to replace a method calls in all the project with mockito

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, android-testing

I would like to know how to mock a method which is called in many places in my android project. For instance I have this class:

```
public class RequestQueue {

    protected RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    protected Context mCtx;

    public RequestQueue(Context context) {
        ...
    }

    public void addRequestToQueue(BaseRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
public class FakeRequestQueue extends RequestQueue {

    public FakeRequestQueue(Context context, int expectedRetCode) {
        super(context);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void addRequestToQueue(BaseRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want is to replace all the calls to `RequestQueue.addRequestToQueue()` by `FakeRequestQueue.addRequestToQueue()` in my whole project. I understand the mock concept but what I found until now is only a way to mock objects locally instantiated.
Thank you.

Comment: You could consider to introduce a dependency injection framework, such as Dagger.

Comment: Could you please explain your question again? I dont understand what you exactly need.. What do you mean by "to replace all the calls to"? Mockito does not make a method replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Using dagger suggested by @rciovati is one solution.

Another solution could be to use robolectric shadow system. A shadow class is like a proxy where you can replace the implementation of your methods. An example can be found at [Robolectric shadow not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629786/robolectric-shadow-not-working)